# How to create a copy of a complete slide in PowerPoint with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm new to PowerPoint, and I've learned that I can insert a new blank slide with Ctrl-M, which is helpful. But it seems there ought to be a simple way to insert a new slide that is a copy of the current slide?

Often I want several consecutive slides to simply add a little more text, so that the audience stays focused on the topic I'm speaking about, which leads me to trying to copy entire slides. But copying a slide that involves multiple 'boxes' seems awkward, as the usual copy shortcuts just grab the text in a single box.

What is the right way to accomplish this? How do you copy an entire slide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PPT 2007: Alt + H I D
(Home | Insert | Duplicate slide)

Pretty sure it works the same in PPT 2010.

Comment: It does indeed.

Answer (score 6):

Select the slide you wish to copy and press `Ctrl + D`.

Comment: right-clicking wouldn't be a "keyboard shortcut" ;) ...unless you have the context-menu soft key on your keyboard

Comment: @warren makes a good point. I'll accept this answer at the end of the day if no better solution arrives. But in the worse case, this does the job well enough.

Comment: @EricWilson After four years, two months and eleven days since your comment, is your day finally over? :> Because you certainly should accept this answer, as it is pretty much faster and easier than currently selected one.

Comment: @trejder I'm sure it is for you, but some of us are slow at these new-fangled pointing devices. Breaks the flow, moves the hands from the home-row, and all that. I accepted the one that I wanted, thank you very much. But you are free to ask a very similar question, for which this would be the correct answer.

Comment: Nah! It was more than joke, since you mentioned "end of day" and left us without "anything" for the next more than four years. Yes, you're right. It is entirely up to you. For me it is pretty fast to press `Ctrl+D` and certainly much faster than using `Alt + HID`, but I know there are many people out there, who are just keyboard-ninjas with those Alt-based multi-step keyboard shortcuts.